# Parallel streams

Tags: concurrency, java-8, java-stream

There is a function, which calculates the most frequent name `(Human[] people`) in parallel. But there is data race. Why?

```
    Map<String, Integer> nameMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        Arrays.stream(people)
                .parallel()
                .filter(p -> p.isAdult())
                .map(Human::getName)
                .forEach(p -> nameMap.put(p, nameMap.containsKey(p) ? nameMap.get(p) + 1 : 1));
        return nameMap.entrySet().parallelStream().max((entry1, entry2) -> entry1.getValue() > entry2.getValue() ? 1 : -1).get().getKey();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you are doing a `get`, then increment and *then* a `put`; in between someone might have already put that entry into `nameMap`.

You could have used `ConcurrentHashMap#merge` that is atomic here, or better use `Collectors.toConcurrentMap`

**EDIT**

You could have done it probably a bit more clear:

```
  Arrays.stream(people)
        .parallel()
        .filter(Human::isAdult)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Human::getName, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue))
        .map(Entry::getKey)
        .get();
```

Just notice that I am close to being sure you don't need `parallel` at all

Comment: I think its better to use `groupingByConcurrent` collector instead, since simple `groupBy` would use heavier merging operations. Would need testing though.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov since the downstream collector is `counting()`, the merging consists of a single addition per common key, which is likely much cheaper than allowing contention at the keys when accumulating. However, it’s even more likely that not doing the operation in parallel is faster than both parallel variants, as you need a really large input data set to get a benefit from parallel processing.

Comment: @Eugene you can replace `Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue)` with [`Entry.comparingByValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue()).